# Adding a sub layer in FramerJS

Tags: javascript, framerjs

I'm trying to add a sub layer to the main set of layers in a framer prototype:

```
myLayers = Framer.Importer.load("imported/some-psd")

layer = new Layer();
myLayers.addSubLayer(layer);
```

But I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function app.js:4
(anonymous function)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the `superLayer` property to the `layer` var, rather than adding layer to myLayers as a subLayer

In other words:

```
myLayers = Framer.Importer.load("import/some-psd")
layer = new Layer()
    superLayer: myLayers
```

Or

```
layer.superLayer = myLayers
```